# Zeppelin : is it possible to send Kafka message in Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zeppelin

I would like to know if it's possible to send Kafka message directly in Zeppelin ?
The Scala script that I want to launch is like this :

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

val kafkaProducerProps: Properties = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "x.data.edh:6667")
    props.put("key.serializer", classOf[StringSerializer].getName)
    props.put("value.serializer", classOf[StringSerializer].getName)
    props
  }

val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](kafkaProducerProps)
producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String]("myTopic", keyMessage._1, keyMessage._2))
```

For me Zeppelin is equivalent to a spark-shell, but I'm not sure if we can send kafka messages in Spark-shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spark Structured Streaming to send a dataframe to Kafka

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka

---

Otherwise, to use a plain Kafka producer, be sure that you're only running one instance of a Spark executor/driver, otherwise you'd be sending multiple events